# Combine videos using Ffmpeg in Lambda and S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, video, ffmpeg, aws-lambda

### Goal

Im making a video converting tool with AWS Lambda where videos can be uploaded using a webpage to a S3 bucket. When all videos (1 or more) are uploaded to the bucket a done.json file will be uploaded last. A Lambda function is called on every upload and only will do something when the final done.json is uploaded.

#### Code walkthrough

Once the done.json is uploaded it will get all the videos in the current folder and convert them using Ffmpeg like this:

```
 i = 0
 ts_video_paths = []
 for video in video_paths:
     video_ts = os.path.splitext(video)[0] + '.ts'
     s3_source_signed_url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params={'Bucket': S3_SOURCE_BUCKET, 'Key': video},  ExpiresIn=SIGNED_URL_TIMEOUT)
                
     ts_video_paths.append(f'/tmp/{rnd}/ts_video{i}.ts')
     ffmpeg_ts_cmd = f'/opt/bin/ffmpeg -i {s3_source_signed_url} -c:v copy -copyts -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts -flags -global_header -af aresample=async=1:first_pts=0 /tmp/{rnd}/ts_video{i}.ts'
     command = shlex.split(ffmpeg_ts_cmd)
     subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
                
     i += 1
```

After all the .ts files are made they will be made into one file (saw somewhere that you can just add .ts files)

```
 data = b''
 for video in ts_video_paths:
   f = open(video, 'rb')
   data += f.read()
            
   f = open(f'/tmp/{rnd}/all.ts', 'wb')
   f.write(data)
   f.close()
```

The last step is to convert the all.ts to a .mp4 video. In this step I sometimes can't an error. It only happens with some videos and I cant find a solution.

```
ffmpeg_combine_cmd = f'/opt/bin/ffmpeg -i /tmp/{rnd}/all.ts -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f mp4 /tmp/{rnd}/video.mp4'
command_final = shlex.split(ffmpeg_combine_cmd)
p2 = subprocess.run(command_final , check=True)  # Sometimes gives an error videos
```

**Error that I get with some video converting:**

```
Command '['/opt/bin/ffmpeg', '-i', '/tmp/CLZHC/all.ts', '-acodec', 'copy', '-vcodec', 'copy', '-f', 'mp4', '/tmp/CLZHC/video.mp4']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

#### My question to you

- Is this the "right" way to tackle this problem?
- Does someone know what the erro is im getting?
- Or can anybody give me tips?

Comment: did you get any solution to that?
I'm trying to decide whether i should use ffmpeg or elastic transcoder